# SCSS mixin skip default arguments

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have some mixin:

```
@mixin flexBox( $directionVlaue: row, $justifyValue: flex-start, $alignValue: baseline ) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: $directionVlaue;
  justify-content: $justifyValue;
  align-items: $alignValue;
}
```

Now if I use it and pass in the arguments is there a possibility to skip one so I dont have to write all three arguments all the time:

```
.thing {
   @include flexBox(row, center, center);
}
```

I don't want to specify `row` here because it is the default. So is it possible to write somthing like:

```
.thing {
   @include flexBox( , center, center); // leave first argument empty
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that but instead, you can use `null` values, With `null`, we can pass a variable with no value and it gets excluded from the CSS output unless we assign a value to it when including the `mixin`.

So in your case : **mixin**

```
@mixin flexBox( $directionVlaue: null, $justifyValue: flex-start, $alignValue: baseline )
```

**@include**

```
.thing {
   @include flexBox(center, center); 
}
```

The null value works in this case because we’re still able to define optional arguments without the unnecessary CSS output. So now, if we pass two values, it will only output those declarations to the CSS.

So as long as you don't define any value, it will be null

Comment: oh nice. That's exactely what I'm looking fore. Since in this case `row` is the browser default.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe keyword arguments? This allows specific arguments to be defined.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#taking-arbitrary-keyword-arguments

Comment: That's interesting. But the SCSS code I would write in this case with flexbox would be almost the same amount of lines as vanilla css. Therefore I think it's a bit over the top.